# Strange speed difference when adding a new item on List (C#)

Tags: c#, performance, list

I've made some speed tests concerning Lists in C#. Here is a result that I cannot explain. I hope someone can figure out what is happening.

Miliseconds for 1000 iterations if cloneList.RemoveAt(cloneList.Count - 1) is called before cloneList.Add(next): x milliseconds.

Miliseconds for 1000 iterations if cloneList.RemoveAt(cloneList.Count - 1) is NOT called before cloneList.Add(next): at least **20x** milliseconds.

It seems if a have one more statement my code get 20 times faster (see the code below):

```
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        Random random = new Random(100);

        TimeSpan caseOneTimeSpan = new TimeSpan();
        TimeSpan caseTwoTimeSpan = new TimeSpan();


        int len = 1000;

        List<int> myList = new List<int>();
        myList.Capacity = len + 1;

        // filling the list
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            myList.Add(random.Next(1000));

        // number of tests (1000)
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            List<int> cloneList = myList.ToList();
            int next = random.Next();

            // case 1 - remove last item before adding the new item
            stopWatch.Start();
            cloneList.RemoveAt(cloneList.Count - 1);
            cloneList.Add(next);
            caseOneTimeSpan += stopWatch.Elapsed;

            // reset stopwatch and clone list

            stopWatch.Reset();
            cloneList = myList.ToList();

            // case 2 - add without removing
            stopWatch.Start();
            cloneList.Add(next);
            caseTwoTimeSpan += stopWatch.Elapsed;


            stopWatch.Reset();

        }

        Console.WriteLine("Case 1: " + caseOneTimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine("Case 2: " + caseTwoTimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine("Case 2 / Case 1: " + caseTwoTimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds / caseOneTimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Comment: I believe this has to do with the way lists are allocated. Initially they get a certain amount of memory allocated and it takes time to reallocate once you go past that. Hopefully someone else can explain this in much more detail than I can...

Comment: The capacity of the list is probably the same as it's length in your caes, so when you add an item after removing one, it has the extra space that hasn't been trimmed, but when you don't, it has to allocate more memory.

Comment: Your 2 cases do completely different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add an item to a list there are two possibilities:

1. The internal buffer is large enough to add another item.  The item is placed in the next free location.  **Speed: O(1)** (This is the most common case.)
2. The internal buffer is *not* large enough.  Create a new, larger, buffer.  Copy all items from the old buffer to the new one.  Add the next item to the new buffer.  **Speed: O(n)** (this shouldn't be occurring often)

While most `Add` calls will be O(1), some are O(n).

Removing the last item is always O(1).

Since `Add` is sometimes dependent on the size of the list, when the list is larger it takes longer (if any calls require a new buffer).  If you always remove items when adding a new one you are ensuring that the internal buffer always has enough space.

You can look at the `Capacity` property of `List` to see the current size of the internal buffer and compare it to `Count`, which is the number of items that the list actually has.  (Therefore `Capacity-Count` is the number of free items in the buffer.)  While not often useful in real programs, looking at these tools when debugging or developing an application can be useful to helping you see what's going on underneath.

Comment: +1 Good answer. Adding to it: You can see the list's Count vs Capacity while debugging it and see the differences.